# How can I check if cgroups are available on my Linux host?

Tags: linux, cgroups, container, unshare

Is there a command to check if the container services are running on a Linux system?  Someone suggested `unshare` but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: Upon re-reading your question, I realized that I had answered a slightly different one. You want to know whether a service is running, and I had originally answered how to tell if a package was installed. To answer your actual question, it depends upon your init system.

1. systemd - the basic command is `systemctl`, which will list all services and their states, so you could either manually browse it manually or pipe it through a `grep` command, like so: `systemctl | grep -e cgmanager -e cgproxy -e cgroupfs-mount`. Or, as user muru suggests in the comments, simply `systemctl status 'cg*'`.
2. sysVinit - the basic command is `service --status-all` and the grep command would be `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -e cgmanager -e cgproxy -e cgroupfs-mount`. Note that in this case, running services are denoted with a `[+]` prefix symbol. Also note that for the grep to work, the redirect `2>&1` must be made for the `service` command.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

1. Maybe the simplest thing to do is try `man cgroups`. If that brings up a documentation page, then your host has the package installed. However, some installs are 'stingy' and don't install `man` pages.
2. You could try `cgm` and see if that produces output. Most installs of `cgroups` will include that command, but not necessarily.
3. You could look up the package list of your host distribution. On debian derivatives, that would be `dpkg -l |grep cgroup`, but occasionally a system will restrict access to `root` or `sudo` for `dpkg`.

There will be a lot of other ways.

Comment: These all work. You can also `cat /proc/mounts` and you'll see  several `cgroups` mounted in  `/sys/fs/cgroup`. For `Fedora` and relatives, you can find the `libcgroup` and `libcgroup-tools` packages with `rpm -qa \*cgroup\*`.

Comment: `systemctl` accepts wildcards, like so: `systemctl status 'cg*'` (or `systemctl list-units 'cg*'`)

Comment: @muru - Thank you. I incorporated your comment into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which cgroup features are enabled in kernel config with:

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CGROUP
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_WRITEBACK=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_RDMA is not set
# CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_SOCK_CGROUP_DATA is not set
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP is not set
# CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO is not set
# CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_CLASSID is not set
```

(note: in order for `/proc/config.gz` to show up

```
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
```

need to be set)

Comment: gzip: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory